# Why does changing the permittivity of the dielectric within a capacitor not have any effect on the electric field opposite the plate?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, electrostatics, electrons, capacitance

Utilizing FEMM 4.2, I built a pair of simple parallel plate capacitors, however I oriented them so that the anodes of these capacitors faced each other. As expected, the electric fields of the two similarly charged surfaces repelled each other.

[image]

My hypothesis was therefore based upon my understanding of the physics of a capacitor and the interactions of an electric field, that by increasing the dielectric constant of the capacitors, more charge would be deposited on the surface of these plates, and consequently more force should be applied. However, upon experimentation, I found that the opposite was actually the case; the capacitors pushed each other away *less* than without a dielectric.

[image]

I also noticed that according to the simulation, the *x-component* did increase by a multiple of six with the current parameters. This does not make any sense to me, at least given my understand of FEA(Which is admittedly extremely limited).

So, why is this not the case that seems to be so intuitive? We know that the electric field surrounding a charge is radial, and that the presence of a polarizing dielectric increases amount of electrons on the surface by canceling the field within the dielectric itself allowing more electrons to be deposited. But if the effects of the electric field are radial, shouldn't the strength of it still be increased outside the presence of the positive charges in the dielectric? Then if more electrons are present on the plate of a capacitor, then opposite the dielectric the field strength should still be increased.

This seems obvious to me, but appears not to be the case. I hesitate to presume the software is incorrect as that would be highly presumptuous, which leads me to conclude my understanding of electric fields is lacking.

Comment: Did you keep the voltage across each capacitor constant or the charge?

Comment: I recreated your system in FEMM and (as expected) the x component of the force is just a numerical artifact. As I increase the fineness of the mesh (i.e. make the computation better) the y component keeps its magnitude but the x component gets smaller. General rule: a (relatively) small number in a computer simulation is probably just an error where there should be a zero.

Comment: I used the prescribed voltage rather than total charge when creating the conductors. I've only recently branched into electrostatics and there appears to be a lot more information about the magnetic side of things in FEMM on the internet for me to study.